# MSSQL Stored Procedure - Return more than one column

Tags: javascript, sql-server, azure-mobile-services

**(If you're here from Google, I [answered my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20940245/1478808) with a fix)**

I have some trouble running a stored procedure from a WAMS (Windows Azure Mobile Service).

It only returns the last row in the relevant table, when I would like to get all the relevant tables for the query.

The stored procedure looks sort of like the following:

```
DECLARE @id bigint

SET @id = 0

IF @var IS NOT NULL AND @var!= 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @id = id FROM intersection WHERE var = @var
    IF @id IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT row1, row2, row3 FROM relevant_table WHERE id = @id
    END
END
```

As you can see, I'm trying to return some rows based on a variable I've defined using the WA SQL Manager Interface.

The procedure executes as it is now, however it only returns the last row I've ever defined, and not all of the rows that's relevant to the ID I get from the 'intersection' table.

My WAMS API script is pretty basic. Executes the Stored Procedure based on a query string value, saves it to a response variable, which it will return.

My intersection table is structured like the following:

```
intesection_id(int)  var(int)   id(int)-foreign key = fkey_0

1                    10009      1
2                    10009      2
```

And my relevant_table is like this:

```
id(int)-foreign key = fkey_0   information    information2   created

1                              "some info"    "other info"   default = getdate()
2                              "other info"   "even more"    --||--
```

The "var" column is yet another foreign key, but that's to a table which is irrelevant to my problem.

Comment: And which column is `foreign key` , relationship between two tables ??

Comment: @M.Ali updated OP again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all of those IF statements. They kind of clutter up the query IMO. Your query could be re-written as follows:

```
;WITH parms AS (SELECT
    [Var] = @var
)

SELECT rt.row1
     , rt.row2
     , rt.row3 
FROM parms p
JOIN intersection isec 
    ON isec.[var] = p.[Var]
JOIN relevant_table rt
    ON rt.id = isec.id
WHERE ISNULL(p.[Var], 0) <> 0
```

This query will return an empty set if `@var` is NULL or `0`. If you just don't want it to select anything at all if `@var` is NULL or if `@var` is not null but `@id` is null then you could still use the nested IF structure in your question, but if that is not your intention then both checks are totally necessary.

Regardless of what you do, the `IF @var IS NOT NULL AND @var!= 0` statement can be summarized with `IF ISNULL(@var, 0) <> 0` which is represented as `WHERE ISNULL(p.[Var], 0) > 0` in my query.

You're also calling your columns "rows" in the last `SELECT`. I left them as "row1, row2, ...".

Comment: Updated my op with how the tables look. I think I'm just at a logical nullpointer with myself here.

Comment: Here's a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/02bc0/1) with a representation of the structure you've appended to your OP and an implementation of my query with parms.Var set to 10009. You spelled the "intersection" table "intesection" in your addition, I kept "intersection" in the example.

Comment: You would change "10009" to "@var" in the "parms" CTE in your own implementation, just like it is in my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much the correct answer. I ended up adding a view with a join similar to you, so that I can easily expand on the view if I want to connect more stored procedures. Thanks!
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20940245/1478808

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, perhaps you should change

```
IF @var IS NOT NULL AND @var!= 0
```

Into

```
IF @var IS NOT NULL AND @var <> 0
```

Comment: Anytime, we live in an era where we code in more languages than we can speak, syntax mix-ups are a day-to-day thing :)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue by going the safe way, and adding a view on top. I can afford it.

T-SQL in View:

```
SELECT
    intersection.intersection_id,
    intersection.var,
    relevant_table.id,
    relevant_table.information,
    relevant_table.information2
FROM
    dbo.intersection
INNER JOIN
    dbo.relevant_table
ON
    relevant_table.id = intersection.id
```

T-SQL in sp:

```
SELECT
    id, information, information2 
FROM
    View
WHERE
    var = @var
```

This let me do pretty much what I wanted.

NODE.js in WAMS Api Editor is as easy as this:

```
var mssql = request.service.mssql;
var sql_query = "EXEC sp_getvar ?";

mssql.query(sql_query, [var], {
    success: function(res) {
        response.send(statusCodes.OK, res)
    },
```

Not having to deal with business logic in my API was my main goal, this basically just makes it easier to add API calls on top of, instead of having to change every individual api file if I wanted to make a change.

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @intersection TABLE (intesection_id INT, [Var] INT, ID INT)
INSERT INTO @intersection
VALUES (1,10009,1),(2,10009,2),(3,10010,2),(4,10010,2)

DECLARE @relevant_table TABLE (id int,information VARCHAR(20),information2 VARCHAR(20)
                               ,created DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @relevant_table
VALUES (1,'some info','other info',getdate()),
(2,'other info','even more',getdate())
```

**Query**

```
DECLARE @id int;
DECLARE @var int;

SET @var = 10009   --<-- @var value from your proc

IF (@var IS NOT NULL AND @var <> 0)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 1 @id = ID FROM @intersection WHERE [Var] = @var
END

IF (@id IS NOT NULL AND @id <> 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @intersection I INNER JOIN @relevant_table R
    ON I.ID = R.id
    WHERE  R.id = @id
END
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════════════╦═══════╦════╦════╦═════════════╦══════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ intesection_id ║  Var  ║ ID ║ id ║ information ║ information2 ║         created         ║
╠════════════════╬═══════╬════╬════╬═════════════╬══════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║              1 ║ 10009 ║  1 ║  1 ║ some info   ║ other info   ║ 2014-01-05 19:42:52.450 ║
╚════════════════╩═══════╩════╩════╩═════════════╩══════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: How stupid can I be! But, considering how I'm using the ID for lookup in the second table, would a loop be better?

Comment: Why would you use loop ??? if you are checking against multiple values use `IN` operator.